# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment no longer exists for key f0: unique id

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-gps

I am a beginner in android and I am not able to understand why I am getting error. When I am clicking on the home button(Bottom Navigation bar) then I am getting this error. I am using shared preference for saving my value when but when this value is retrieved then an error is coming.

MyActivityCode:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getLastLocation();

    binding.bottmNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.home1: //when i m clicking here
                    setFragment(homeFragment);
                    SharedPreferences shprefs = getSharedPreferences(prefs, MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences mprefs = getSharedPreferences(myprefs, MODE_PRIVATE);
                    String savedvalue = shprefs.getString("savedvalue", null);
                    String savedcountry = mprefs.getString("savedcountry", null);
                    if ((savedvalue != null && savedvalue.equals("India")) || savedcountry.equals("India")) {
                        newsModels.clear();
                        binding.bottmNav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.location).setTitle("India");
                        binding.bottmNav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.home1).setChecked(true);
                        setindianewsdata();
                        setindiashopdata();
                        setFragment(homeFragment);
                    } else if (savedvalue.equals("Usa") || savedcountry.equals("Usa")) {
                        newsModels.clear();
                        setusanewsdata();
                        setusashopdata();
                        setFragment(homeFragment);
                        binding.bottmNav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.location).setTitle("USA");
                        binding.bottmNav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.home1).setChecked(true);
                    }
                    return true;
                case R.id.location:
                    final AlertDialog.Builder mbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this);
                    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
                    Button okbutton = v.findViewById(R.id.okbutton);
                    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                    ArrayAdapter < String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (HomeActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_list));
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                    mbuilder.setView(v);
                    final AlertDialog dialog = mbuilder.create();
                    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

                    okbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(prefs, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                            editor.putString("savedvalue", spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                            editor.commit();
                            String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            newsModels = new ArrayList < > ();
                            if (text.equals("India")) {
                                newsModels.clear();
                                setindianewsdata();
                                setindiashopdata();
                                setFragment(homeFragment);
                                binding.bottmNav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.location).setTitle("India");
                                binding.bottmNav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.home1).setChecked(true);
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            } else if (text.equals("Usa")) {
                                newsModels.clear();
                                setusanewsdata();
                                setusashopdata();
                                setFragment(homeFragment);
                                binding.bottmNav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.location).setTitle("USA");
                                binding.bottmNav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.home1).setChecked(true);
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}


public void getLastLocation() {
    if (checkPermissions()) {
        if (isLocationEnabled()) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(
                new OnCompleteListener < Location > () {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < Location > task) {
                        Location location = task.getResult();
                        if (location == null) {
                            requestNewLocationData();
                        } else {
                            countryname = findcountry(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                            handlevalue(countryname);
                            if (countryname.equals("India")) {
                                newsModels.clear();
                                setindianewsdata();
                                setindiashopdata();
                                TypedArray socialimg = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.social_image);
                                String[] socialname = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.social_name);
                                String[] socialhref = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.social_url);
                                socialModels = new ArrayList < > ();
                                for (int k = 0; k < socialimg.length(); k++) {
                                    SocialModel socialModel = new SocialModel(socialimg.getResourceId(k, 0), socialname[k], socialhref[k]);
                                    socialModels.add(socialModel);
                                }
                                SocialSingleton.getConstant().addNewsModel(socialModels);
                                setFragment(homeFragment);
                                binding.bottmNav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.location).setTitle("India");
                                binding.bottmNav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.home1).setChecked(true);
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            } else if (countryname.equals("USA")) {
                                TypedArray indianewslogo = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.usnews);
                                setusanewsdata();
                                setusashopdata();
                                setFragment(homeFragment);
                                binding.bottmNav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.location).setTitle("USA");
                                binding.bottmNav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.home1).setChecked(true);
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Turn on location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } else {
        requestPermissions();

    }
}

    private void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

}
```

When I am clicking on the home button then I am getting this error. Don't know why.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment no longer exists for key f0: unique id 2b2916b8-40c2-4190-b2d7-e6440a7592eb
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getFragment(FragmentManagerImpl.java:365)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.restoreState(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:309)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onRestoreInstanceState(ViewPager.java:1461)
    at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:18042)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3859)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3865)
    at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:18020)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:548)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:907)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
    at
```

Comment: Can you specify on which line your app is throw this exception ?

Comment: As far as I see the problem is in your View Pageradapter. You trying to get fragment which is not created yet

Comment: not on any specific line, even in the error there is no line no mentioned. but when i am clicking home button from bottom navigation bar then app is crashing.

Comment: I thing the problem in your function setFragment. Can you put it in you question above ?

Comment: yes i updated the code.

Comment: Try replace it line setFragment(homeFragment); on this line  setFragment(new HomeFragment());

Comment: Yeah issue resolved. Thank you so,much

Comment: Give me a thumbs up on my last comment please

Answer (score 9):

seting setSaveEnabled() to false into our viewpager